# How to change pagination result for filter with Get method Codeigniter

Tags: php, sorting, codeigniter, filter, pagination

I need help about Codeigniter pagination, sort and filter. My problem is Im filtering products but when I click next button it all resetting. I want to pagination with filtered ones with get method. Here is my codes;
Controller:

```
  $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "ilanlar";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->ilan_model->get_count($posted_items);
    $config["per_page"] = 10;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["row"] = $this->product_model->get_row($posted_items);
    $data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_products($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data['get'] = $_GET;

    $this->load->view('pages/product/product', $data);
```

Model

```
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$this->db->where('status',2);
if(!empty($get['min'])){
    $this->db->where('ad_price>='.$get['min']);
    }
    if(!empty($get['max'])) {
        $this->db->where('ad_price<=' .$get['max']);
    }
$query = $this->db->get('ad_table');
return $query->result();
```

my url must be something like this.

```
myapp.com/list/0?min=50&max=300
```

but when I click next page It changes myapp.com/list/10

Thank you guys already.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable `reuse_query_string` with this configuration
`$config ['reuse_query_string'] = true;`

**Check the below code, you can add above line like below:**

```
$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "ilanlar";
$config["total_rows"] = $this->ilan_model->get_count($posted_items);
$config["per_page"] = 10;
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
$config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```